# How can I separate one single column into multiple rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, split, rows

I've got a long vertical list in Excel which contains names and comments. The order is always the same, each comment is preceded and followed by the name of the person who made the comment. As a consequence, it has the following form:

```
name1
comment1
name1
name2
comment2
name2
name3
...
```

For example:

```
John Smith
I really liked the movie, because it was never boring.
John Smith
Jane Doe
It was the worst movie I have ever seen, a waste of my money. Would not recommend.
Jane Doe
Jake Nemo
...
```

The order is always the same (**name1-comment1-name1**-*name2-comment2-name2*-**name3...**), so each three cells belong together (**1-3**, *4-6*, **7-9**...).

What I want to do is divide this vertical Excel-column into separate rows, in which each row contains the name (twice) and comment of one person. In other words, I always want to always take three cells and turn these  into a row. This way each row should contain the three cells with the name and comment of a single person:

```
name1, comment1, name1
name2, comment2, name2
name3...
```

So I want to go from this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEp1E.png)

To this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUD24.png)

It would be too much work to do this manually for the entire column, as the list is very long. Would there be a way to do this automatically? 
I do not have a lot of experience, so really concrete and practical steps would be very appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Btw, I just had a look at your profile and you have 12 open questions. I suggest you go back and revisit these questions and see where you can accept/upvote answers to your questions. People take time to help you out, and it's simply courtesy to reward those people the way this site has intended. If you are unfamiliar with the system then take the site's [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `A1` on let's say `Sheet2!` put the following:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,((ROW()-1)*3)+COLUMN())
```

Where `Sheet1!` represents the sheet with all the data. Now, drag right and down

Comment: Thank you and I will!